# Polygon buffer by distance

Tags: qgis, distance, buffer

I am working with a world map shape file in the Spherical Equidistant Projection (Equirectangular) in QGIS 3.4. When creating a buffer using the VectorGeometry>Buffer function set for distance in meters (no degress), the resulting buffer appears as consistent width around the entire object (continents in this case). This seems wrong to me because in the Equirectangular projection 1000 meters (for example) in latitude direction at the equator appears less than 1000 meters near the poles. I would expect the buffer to get wider as latitude increases from the equator when working in this projection.

My goal is create an map with line widths that when actually applied to sphere will appear with a consistent width line width around the object. The lines need to get wider as they approach the poles to accomplish this.

If not the buffer function, which function would create the result I am attempting to achieve?

Comment: Which software is that?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @Taras QGIS 3.4 (added edit to initial post)